# How Can I display all keyboard keys in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have quick question about displaying all keyboard keys in combobox. How to do it because I have no idea and I can't find anything about this in google so I'm here for  some help. I know i must do something like:

```
foreach(string Key in Keyboard){ combobox1.Items.Add(Key); }
```

Comment: There is no single list of keyboard keys. Consider different keyboard layouts (US 101 layout vs. UK 102 layout) or different keyboard makers adding their own custom buttons (e.g. my Logitech keyboard has extra macro keys and media-keys). So what do you actually want to display?

Comment: I want to display all default Keys like (A, B, C, D ,{ENTER}, {BACKSPACE}) and other

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8) is an `enum` that lists *most* PC keyboard scancodes (note that scancodes do not necessarily map 1:1 directly to physical keys).

Loading them into a ComboBox is straightforward. I recommend using DataBinding with the ComboBox to avoid problems caused by identical enum values with different names (which would be rendered with the first name shared by both values).

```
class KeyItem
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<KeyItem> List { get; } = CreateList();

    private static IReadOnlyList<KeyItem> CreateList()
    {
        String[] names  = Enum.GetNames( typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Keys) );
        Key[]    values = Enum.GeValues( typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Keys) );

        return Enumerable
            .Range( 0, names.Length )
            .Select( i => new KeyItem( values[i], names[i] ) )
            .ToList();
    }

    private KeyItem( Key key, String name )
    {
        this.KeyCode = key;
        this.Name    = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    public Key    KeyCode { get; }
    public String Name    { get; }
}

comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(KeyItem.Name);
comboBox1.ValueMember   = nameof(KeyItem.KeyCode);
comboBox1.DataSource    = KeyItem.List;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```